# How to choose a mother board which is compatible with all the old components

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, capacitor

[My system configs](https://gofile.io/d/5PRbeY)
I have been facing some weird issues that I can't find solution to

1 : At times while I am working on my system, the screen completely freezes, no response, it does not restarts on its own, but if I force one there is just black screen and no booting

then I have to plug in and out my CPU and do power on and off several times before it finally boots and pops some "Your pc ran into a problem" and restarts

2:At times when I am working, it restarts on its own

3:At times when I wake up in the morning and try to switch it off, the fans dont start and there is just black screen, it starts after switching on and off, power cables and doing random trials

[This is my mother board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVqTH.png)

I am guessing my motherboard maybe an issue becuase it even has some swollen capacitors, I dont know if thats the case correct me please if thats so.

`**So all I wanted was to know what are the things i should consider to buy a new motherboard such that it is compatible with my old processor, ram and every other component and i wont need to buy any thing but new motherbaord
NOTE BUYING A NEW COMPUTER ISNT AN OPTION**`

Answer (score 1):

For a computer that is around 9 years old, it is unlikely that you will find a new
motherboard that is compatible with all your components.
You are likely to find that the new motherboard has a problem with one or more
components and will need to invest in more hardware.

I think your best two options are:

- Find the exact same motherboard on the internet
- Buy a new computer.

Comment: @AliAsifKhan - The file you uploaded is inaccessible.  Use the edit feature to add the details into the body of the question.  However, questions seeking hardware recommendations, are not within scope.  **Based on just the chipset you won’t find new hardware that’s compatible with your CPU.**